# How to make nested list appear below the parent list item?

Tags: html, css, css-position, nested-lists

```js
function ServicesMenu() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("services-cont")[0].classList.toggle("showS");
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

*{padding:0;margin:0;}

body{min-width:300px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background:#f8f8f8 }

.wrapper {
 max-width: 980px;
 height:2000px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 position: relative; 
 background-color: #fff;
}

header{
 width:980px;
 height:105px;
 background:  #e60000;
}

ul.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 top:63px;
 right:60px;
    width: 560px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}

ul.navbar li {
 display:inline-block;
 Margin-left:15px;
 background: black;
}

ul.navbar li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

ul.navbar li a:hover {background-color: #660000;}

.services-cont{display: none;}

.services-cont.showS { 
 list-style-type: none;
 display: block;
 background-color: #707070 ;
 }

.services-cont.showS li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
 height:0;
 border:none;
  }
  
.services-cont.showS li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menustyle.css">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1" />

<script src="MenuFunc.js"></script>

<Title>Menu</title>

</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 
<header>

 </header>
 
 <ul class="navbar">

  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ServicesMenu()">Services</a>
   <ul class="services-cont">
    <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>      
    <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

 </ul>

</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

However, the parent `<li>` appears on top with the nested list below and the rest `<li>` of the parent list are below aligned with the end of the child list.

How do I get the parent list items **Home, Services and Contact** horizontally aligned in a **straight line**?

[image]

[image]

Comment: where is your html and css code? what have you tried?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

The `position: absolute` and `overflow: hidden` properties were interfering and not allowing the dropdown list to display properly. I have commented them in the code so you can see.

You should refrain from using absolute positioning where you can achieve the same effect by simply nesting the tags properly. For instance, I nested your `navbar` inside the red `header`.

### Code

Press the 'Run code snippet' button below to see the code output.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #f8f8f8
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 980px;
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  /*position: relative;*/
  background-color: #fff;
}
header {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 980px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #e60000;
}
.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  top: 63px;
  right: 60px;
  width: 560px;
  display: block;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  Margin-left: 15px;
  background: black;
}
.navbar li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.navbar li a:hover {
  background-color: #660000;
}
.navbar li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
  background-color: #707070;
}
.navbar li ul li {
  float: none;
  display: inline;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
}
.navbar li ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.navbar li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>
  <Title>Menu</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Service 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Service 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Service 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

You need to add the following two line of CSS code for the nested `<li>` tag.

```
ul li ul {    
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
}
```

Setting the position to absolute and top to auto will display your nested ul under the parent tag.

### Code

Press the 'Run code snippet' button below to see the code output.

```css
ul li {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
ul li ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: grey;
  /*YOU NEED THE TWO LINES BELOW*/
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
}
ul li ul li {
  color: white;
  background: grey;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Home
    </li>
    <li>
      Services
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      Contact
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but doesn't work with my code. When I add these two lines, the nested list doesn't appears.